# download/extract .msg files from folders a subfolders in Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I would like be able to download/extract .msg files from folders a subfolders in Outlook. And possibly keep the structure.

```
folder
     subfolder 1
                subfolder 1.A
                subfolder 1.B                    
     subfolder 2 
                subfolder 2.A
                subfolder 2.B 
          etc.
```

Can you please show a direction how it can be done?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook using python win32com to iterate subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849742/outlook-using-python-win32com-to-iterate-subfolders)

Comment: You should explain what you have tried to do to solve the problem, including some code.

Answer (score 0):

The [Outlook using python win32com to iterate subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849742/outlook-using-python-win32com-to-iterate-subfolders) thread explains how to iterate over all subfolders. Using recursion you may go through each folder in Outlook. And with each iteration you can create a subfolder on a disk where you can save messages.

The [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

Note, Outlook folders may contain different kind if items - appointments, tasks, notes, documents and etc. So, I'd suggest checking the [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.class) property at runtime to make sure you deal with mail items only.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestions, I will try to implement this.

Comment: so far, I have managed to write script for downloading .msg files from one specific folder 

`my_folder = mapi.Folders['folder'].Folders['sub1'].Folders['sub2'].Folders['sub3'].Folders['sub4'].Folders['sub5']

for msg in my_folder.Items:
    msgname = msg.subject
    msgname=str(msgname)
    msg.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+msgname)`

Comment: You can iterate over all folder in Outlook recursively, see thread mentioned in my post for more information on that.

Comment: yes, this answer worked, Thanks!   https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709316/8956217