# download recurring appointments but all appointments start date show 1st same date

Tags: python, outlook, calendar, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to get all appointments from client outlook with python and win32com. client,
there are several recurring appointments in calendar A. however, when I download these recurring appointments through python, it only shows the 1st appointment start date instead of each different dates.
IncludeRecurrences = True was used in my coding; how can i modify my python coding? thanks

Example: a recurring appointment happens on the first of every month in 2024. I want to show 12 INSTANCES, with 12 DIFFERENT start dates (01/01/2024, 02/01/2024, etc) but currently only shows 01/01/2024 and repeat 12 times.

```
    import win32com.client, datetime
    import time
    import os
    import email
    import imaplib
    import pandas as pd
    import xlsxwriter
    import datetime as dt
    import calendar as ccc
    from datetime import timedelta
    
    MailboxToAccess = "my_mail@outlook.com"
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
    recip = outlook.CreateRecipient(MailboxToAccess)    
    mail_box = outlook.Folders["A_mailbox"] 
    calendar = mail_box.Folders["Calendar"].Items
    
    
    calendar.IncludeRecurrences = True
    calendar.Sort('[Start]')
    _today=datetime.date.today()[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdnV3.png)
    first_day = datetime.date(_today.year, _today.month, 1)
    this_month_end = datetime.datetime(_today.year, _today.month, ccc.monthrange(_today.year, _today.month)[1])
     
     
    restriction = "[Start] >= '" + str(first_day) + "' AND [END] <= '" + str(this_month_end) + "'"
    
    print (restriction)
    calendar = calendar.Restrict(restriction)
```

Comment: So what do you see in the `calendar` collection?

Comment: it's like this to repeat the same date, 
for folder in calendar:
    print (folder.GetOrganizer(),";",folder.Start,";",folder.Subject)


Damon ; 2024-03-06 08:00:00+00:00 ; Calendar test1
Damon ; 2024-03-06 08:00:00+00:00 ; Calendar test1
Damon ; 2024-03-06 08:00:00+00:00 ; Calendar test1
Damon ; 2024-03-06 08:00:00+00:00 ; Calendar test1

Comment: Have you read the online help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences In particular the large pink box saying: " Caution. Filtering on a sorted list of occurrences will cause the IncludeRecurrences property not to work as expected. For example, the following sequence will return all appointment occurrences; recurring and non-recurring: (1) Sort by Start property (2) Set property to False (3) call Restrict (i.e., filter)." The code example suggests doing the Sort first, and then the IncludeRecurrences.

Comment: I have tried the sort ->IncludeRecurrences or IncludeRecurrences ->sort ...etc. the result still the same...the recurring appointments all show the first date only. however, the same recurring  appointments DID show in different day chart in outlook calendar. even more, the same recurring appointments invite the another mailbox(ie bbb@outlook.com), the python coding could get the curate recurring date from bbb's calendar (regardless the order of sorting/IncludeRecurrences )

Answer (score 0):

First, if you deal with a shared calendar in Outlook, you need to use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). In that case you will not have to build the codebase on string literals:

```
mail_box = outlook.Folders["A_mailbox"] 
calendar = mail_box.Folders["Calendar"]
```

Also pay attention to the following code which re-assigns the `calendar` object:

```
calendar = calendar.Restrict(restriction)
```

The `Restrict` method returns a new `Items` instance with the result of filtering. It makes sense to separate two objects to distinguish them later.

Finally, in the code sample it is not clear how the result collection is used further. You may find the article which I wrote for the technical blog more than a decade ago helpful, see [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/).

Comment: mail_box = outlook.Folders["A_mailbox"]   
calendar = mail_box.Folders["Calendar"]  
these is to get the calendar from shared mailbox, there are many shared mail box in my outlook, 
in order to get the target calendar, i have to point to right shared mailbox first and then go to its calendar folder, just like this <https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404310/23525641>